# Can the window title be modified?

Tags: graphics, windows, testing-and-verification

I would like to modify the window title upon initialisation so that the code base is readily identifiable, e.g. Live, Beta, Development, etc.  Apparently some systems use different colours to make this obvious.  Different frame colours would be great too, but the title would be a very handy place to identify the code base.  (Required for Mathematica on Windows.)

I think the ideal solution would be at startup to modify the string "Wolfram Mathematica 11.2" and replace it with "Beta - Mathematica 11.2", for example.

*Examples*

[image]

Comment: `CurrentValue[EvaluationNotebook[],WindowTitle]=FileBaseName@NotebookFileName[]<> " - beta"`?

Comment: @Kuba - Thanks but I would need Live/Beta to be visible on all generated notebooks in the session, along with the notebook name, (unless overridden).

Comment: Could you clarify for me how you determine what the code base is? Is this determined by the directory the notebook is in?

Comment: @chuy The code base is linked using init.m setting an additional path and loading function declarations.

Answer (score 1):

Give up trying to add to window title and use status area instead, e.g.

```
SetOptions[$FrontEnd, WindowStatusArea -> "Live"]
```